# Cloud Foundry instance suddenly deleted by itself

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

The other day, an instance of cloud foundry was suddenly deleted without permission. The organization and space still exist, but only the instance seems to have been deleted en masse. If you know the possible cause, please let me know. Or tell us how to identify the cause.

We investigated the dashboard for any history of deletion, but found nothing that looked like a trace.

Comment: Deleted or deactivated? Free plan or paid? Activity Tracker records?

Comment: Deleted , and use Free plan. Sorry I don't know "Activity Tracker records". I predict if  I can see "Activity Tracker records" , but I don't know how to see it. Can I tell us?

Comment: If you have a Lite account, you can only see "live logs", not go back in history. You can search the IBM Cloud docs to learn about Activity Tracker. I assume that you already did that, right?

Answer (score 0):

Since Cloud Foundry is already [deprecated](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry-public?topic=cloud-foundry-public-deprecation) and all instances will be permanently removed on 1 June 2023 you should already move to other options - IBM Code Engine, IBM Kubernetes Service, RedHat OpenShift on IBM Cloud service.